# How to relative addressing from C:\ to D:\ in html

Tags: html

for example :

My image is in `D:\temp\img.jpg` 
But my current location and Source html file is in `C:\`

I want to access to image with relative addressing (no absolute)

Comment: Uhm... what? Can you please be a bit more specific on your current situation?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: Use full Windows path to the file like : `"E:\folder\file.txt"` for testing purpose.

Comment: I want to access to image with relative addressing (no absolute)

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to access a drive other than the one you're on, you cannot use relative addressing. You must provide the fully qualified path to the resource you want to access.

For example:

```
<img src="D:\temp\img.jpg">
```

Of course, you'll need to host the image at an accessible location if you plan to run this website on the interwebs. A commercial web server won't be able to access your D: drive.